# Overload operator* without allocating new memory

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, move-semantics

I have class `foo` that manages a `vector` of `float`s of fixed length and some metadata. I have implemented a naive overload for operator*:

```
constexpr int numOfElements = 9;
class foo {
public:
    foo()
        : x(0), y(0), data(numOfElements)
    {}

    foo operator*(float value) {
        foo result;
        for (size_t k = 0; k < this->data.size(); ++k)
            result.data[k] = this->data[k] * value;
        return result;
    }

    int x;
    int y;
    std::vector<float> data;
};
```

later, I use it in the following way:

```
some_foo = *ptr_to_another_foo * 5;
```

where `some_foo` and `ptr_to_another_foo` were defined elsewhere and hold some values. This computes the correct result. However, `result foo` in the overloaded operator creates another object which causes memory allocation which is unacceptable due to performance reasons. Since `some_foo` already has memory allocated for `data`, is there a way to implement the overloaded operator in such a way that `some_foo.data`s memory will be used instead of allocating the temporary `foo result`?

I could always implement a C-like pointer-based multiplication function, but I would like to do something more idiomatic in C++.

Comment: Is `numOfElements` guaranteed to remain `constexpr`?

Comment: I think you're looking for implementing an `operator *=` overload, and then executing `some_foo = *ptr_to_another_foo; some_foo *= 5;`.

Comment: @lubgr - yes. The size of the data vector is fixed and known at compile-time

Comment: currently your operator returns a `foo` value. No matter how you put it, that returned `foo` has its own vector member

Comment: @idclev463035818. This is what I would like to avoid. I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, this will solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a `operator*=` that multiplies the elements in place:

```
foo& operator*=(float value) {
    for (size_t k = 0; k < this->data.size(); ++k)
        this->data[k] *= value;
    return *this;
}
```

If later you realize that you do need also `operator*` you can implement it in terms of `operator*=`:

```
foo operator*(float value) const {
    foo result = *this;
    result *= value;
    return result;
}
```

Note that `operator*` is expected to return a new object and not modify `this` (it should be a `const` method), while `operator*=` is expected to return a reference to `*this` (after modifying it). If you want to make the operation in place, better use the compound `*=`.

Comment: If all the following elements `(vecA - vecB) * (vecC - vecD)` are using a struct vec3 is it a good idea to use `operator*(` or  ``operator-(` amd retiurn a new instance after each operation for readability or will it create a large amount of object allocations or will these allocations be removed by a compiler?

Answer (score 2):

Do not return a `foo`. Instead, return a wrapper object which refers to `*this` and can be used as operand for assignment into another `foo`, changing its state with the multiplied values. This has the caveat that the returned wrapper becomes invalid in case the referred `foo` is destroyed.

A general pattern for this idea is called *expression templates*. This is commonly used in linear algebra libraries.

Comment: out of curiosity: did you actually ever implement expression templates? Is there a library that enables expr templates for arbitrary types? Or is this something mainly found in highly specialized algebra libraries?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I've never implemented expression templates. Here's a library: https://boostorg.github.io/yap/doc/html/index.html Linear algebra is the first area where expression templates were implemented to my knowledge, but I know that Boost Spirit uses them outside of that domain.